# select all Checkboxes by clicking on the top cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-props, checkboxlist

Сode in three files. In setList () you need to pass an array of objects to allocate, but they are generated using map. What is the right thing to do? in general I am trying to adapt my code to this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-all-checkbox-jbub2 But there the array for the Checkbox is moved to a separate file, and mine is generated using map.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-butterfly-0s4ff?file=/src/TableBody/TableBody.jsx

1-file)

```
 let Checkbox = () => {
      
        return (
            <div>
                <label className={s.checkbox}>
                    <input className={s.checkbox__input} type="checkbox"/>
                        <span className={s.checkbox__fake}></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

2-file)

```
 const Tablehead = (handleSelectAll, isCheckAll ) => {
        return (
            <thead className = {s.header}>
            <tr className = {s.area}>
              <th ><Checkbox name="selectAll" id="selectAll" handleClick={handleSelectAll}  isChecked={isCheckAll}/>
</th>            
            </tr>   
          </thead>
        )
    }
```

3-file)

```
const TableBody = ({droplets}) => {
    
        const [isCheckAll, setIsCheckAll] = useState(false);
        const [isCheck, setIsCheck] = useState([]);
        const [list, setList] = useState([]);
      
        useEffect(() => {
          setList();
        }, [list]);
      
        const handleSelectAll = e => {
          setIsCheckAll(!isCheckAll);
          setIsCheck(list.map(li => li.id));
          if (isCheckAll) {
            setIsCheck([]);
          }
        };
      
        const handleClick = e => {
          const { id, checked } = e.target;
          setIsCheck([...isCheck, id]);
          if (!checked) {
            setIsCheck(isCheck.filter(item => item !== id));
          }
        };
    
        return (
            <>
                {droplets.map((droplet, index, id, name ) =>
    
                    <tr className={s.area} key={index}   >
                        <td ><Checkbox  key={id} name={name}  handleClick={handleClick}   isChecked={isCheck.includes(id)}/></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" className={s.button}><Edit /></button></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" className={s.button}><Trash /></button></td>
                    </tr>
                )
                }
            </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code sandbox link?

Comment: Your `Checkbox` Component doesn't seem to accept  `handleClick` method and you did not handle the checkbox - check, uncheck actions.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-butterfly-0s4ff?file=/src/TableBody/TableBody.jsx

Comment: Hey your api is failing at my end - cannot see anything. Can you insert some dummy data instead of using API. I can quickly edit your code to solve the issue if you can do that :)

Comment: I can do this, but if I create an array with data locally, then it will turn out like in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-all-checkbox-jbub2
but what I need is using data from the API

Comment: Can't open this link? https: //api.npoint.io/324f4ca2cdd639760638/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are several problems here

1. Component `Checkbox` doesn't take any props
2. `const Tablehead = (handleSelectAll, isCheckAll)` should be `const Tablehead = ({ handleSelectAll, isCheckAll })`

**And most important one is your `TableHead` and `TableBody`Components both need this checkbox information so you need to lift your state up from `TableBody` to `Table` Component.**

Also the example code you are following seems to do a lot of redundant things which are not necessary to implement your feature. Simply storing a `checked` property in each of your `droplets` should be enough and two functions to toggle individual and toggle all.

So I made the above changes in your code-sandbox link.

Here is the **[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-hooks-1ctyl)**